# Is it possible to hook a module below the list of Customers in backoffice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am working on a module, that has to add some HTML code under the list of customers in backoffice.

Are there any hooks on the 'Customers' page in backofice?
I could only find displayAdminCustomers Hook in the documentation, but this is actually a hook for a separate Customer page.

So, what would be the best way to include some HTML code under the list of Customers?

Answer (score 1):

There are few solutions:

1. hook to the "footer" and check for the customers list page
2. add a new hook overriding the template & controller
3. use jQuery to add the necessary code
4. override the controller the display your custom template or fetch the current one and add your code

All the solutions have pros and cons based on what code you need to insert there.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. First option seems to work fine. It adds code to the very bottom of the page, but I am lifting it up using jquery: `$('#myelement').insertAfter('table.customer');`
But what would be the best way to check for Customers list page?
Currently I am using this check:
`if(Tools::getValue('controller') == 'adminCustomers')`
but it affects other customer related pages, like adding/editing customer

Answer (score 0):

Do you try the hook: displayAdminCustomersListAfter ?